# Converting Swift array to CFArray in Xcode 8 (Swift 3)

Tags: swift, swift3

This no longer works in Xcode 8 beta 6:

```
let colors:CFArray = [fromColor.cgColor, toColor.cgColor]
```

or

```
let gradient:CGGradient = CGGradient(colorsSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), colors:[fromColor.cgColor, toColor.cgColor], locations:[0.0, 1.0])!
```

The error is: Contextual type 'CFArray' cannot be used with array literal

What's the latest way to convert from array to CFArray?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It works if you add the cast `as CFArray`:

```
let colors = [fromColor.cgColor, toColor.cgColor] as CFArray
```

or you can add the cast in a call:

```
let gradient = CGGradient(colorsSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), colors:[fromColor.cgColor, toColor.cgColor] as CFArray, locations:[0.0, 1.0])!
```

In Swift 3 (Xcode 8 beta 6), implicit casting to bridged types [has been removed.](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0072-eliminate-implicit-bridging-conversions.md)  In some cases, like this one, you will need to add explicit casting to make it work.

Comment: @能蟹仔, I just verified that this still works in the released Xcode 8 with Swift 3.0.  If you have an example that does not work, post it as a new question.